# MATLAB ResizeFcn callback fails

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-figure

I am editing a GUI written in MATLAB and have a line in the OpeningFcn that sets the callback for resizing the figure.

```
set(hObject, 'UserData', handles.ParentFig, 'ResizeFcn',@cbFigResize, 'CloseRequestFcn', @Cancel);
```

The callback is pasted below with much edited out for simplicity.

```
function cbFigResize(src,evt)
% check if figure width is less than 600
if fpos(3) < 600 
    %set min. width to 600
    fpos(3) = 600
end
%check if figure height is less than 560
if fpos(4) <560
    % set minimum height to 560
    fpos(4) = 560;
end
```

My coworker runs Windows XP and an earlier version of MATLAB.  I run Windows 7 and MATLAB 7.12.0.635.  Now when he resizes figures they always resize properly.  When I run the same code I can sometimes get the figure smaller than the above set minimum width and height limits.  My coworker says it is a Windows 7 interrupt problem.  If anybody else out there has this problem we found a simple but illogical workaround which I will post below.

```
function cbFigResize(src,evt,doStop)
if nargin < 3
    doStop = false;
end

% check if figure width is less than 600
if fpos(3) < 600 
    %set min. width to 600
    fpos(3) = 600
end
%check if figure height is less than 560
if fpos(4) <560
    % set minimum height to 560
    fpos(4) = 560;
end

if ~doStop
    cbFigResize(src,evt,true)
end
```

You can see that this function calls itself with a flag that stops if from becoming an infinite loop.  And now I cannot resize windows below the minimum.  Has anybody any insights into this behavior?

Comment: Can you expand the post to show the code that's actually setting figure properties after fpos is calculated?

Comment: fpos is set in the fig properties in guide.  There are no changes to fpos besides the one above in the code.  The code I have not included is just a maze of setting button positions based on the height and width of fpos.  But no changes to fpos besides the one above.  A user may resize the window which sets fpos but that is somewhere in MATLAB and not in my code.

Answer (score 1):

A user on mathworks.com answered this question.  His solution solved the problem.  I will put the link below.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21294-matlab-resizefcn-callback-fails